# How to format amount values for French locale

Tags: oracle

We are using a stored procedure in Oracle 12c to calculate and return some amounts. As we have clients in various countries, we received a requirement to display the amounts as per French Locale format based a a particular environment variable.

Here is the exact issue:

The regular amount format would be like 5,000.00

For this, we use `select (TRIM(TO_CHAR('5000','999,999,999,999,999.99') ))  from dual;`

-->5,000.00

But for French locale, it should be returned like **5 000,00**

Please suggest if Oracle provides any functions to support amounts based on Locales than using Replace over the above statement when the locale is French:

```
select replace(replace((TRIM(TO_CHAR('5000','999,999,999,999,999.99') )),',',' '),'.',',')  from dual;
```

--> 5 000,00

Comment: This sounds like something that would be better solved in your presentation layer than in your queries.

Comment: That's a valid point, but we are appending the amount to the amount type, which is a text and returning it as a single column like 'Hotel Expenses 1,000.00'. Hence the Java developers mentioned that it is difficult to implement it in the Java layer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set NLS_TERRITORY parameter at a session level:

```
alter session set nls_territory='FRANCE';

select to_char('5000', 'fm99G999D00') as french
  from dual;
Result:

FRENCH   
----------
5 000,00
```

Comment: The important part of the answer is not the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting (with the OP will find may already be set for their current locale) but using the `G` and `D` format models for the thousands- and decimal-separators (rather than hard-coding `,` and `.`).

Comment: Can  'fm99G999D00' used for the regular formatting as well? So far we've been using (TRIM(TO_CHAR('5000','999,999,999,999,999.99') )) for getting the amounts in proper format!